# Did the prophet ever seek a doctor or tabib?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, life

In our class, once our teacher said, have you ever heard our prophet went to a doctor? Then he explained, he did not because if you eat less (according to Islamic principles) you will never get sick and will not need a doctor. *Note this para is only a reference, I do not need answer to this part*

**My question is, did the prophet ever see a doctor**. It is quite normal that one can get sick and would need to see a doctor but on the other hand, the status of the prophet is so high that it is inappropriate for him to seek a doctor as God is with him and he is more knowledgeable.

Comment: Oddly enough, I was researching the other day on diabetes / Islam / Ramadan - and I remembered a document for patient treatment suggesting that Muhammad had indeed seen a doctor and taken the advice. Unfortunately, they did not cite a reference, but: see point 8 here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1279173/ actually, that same article may have other valid points on this subject, for example the "the sanctity of life" value. I should add: while diet is helpful in general health, it is not the only factor involved. Eating less does not guarantee health.

Comment: @MarcGravell that is a very interesting point but with no valid reference.

Comment: Seeing a doctor is merely "seeking the means" to something - it doesn't necessarily put the doctor at a higher level or status, so I don't see why it would be inappropriate. The Prophet (saws) always consulted experts in any field he needed information on (two examples I can recall right now are people's lineages and military strategy). That said, I don't know whether he (saws) was sick enough at any point to require the services of a doctor and if he ever saw anyone.

Comment: Why wouldn't he? After all, he is simply a man as he insists (though also a prophet with a greater nobility of soul).

Answer (score 5):

Ever heard of the Prophetic Medicine? There are many advices from the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) to cure some ailments. These are recorded in Authentic [Hadeeths](http://abdurrahman.org/sunnah/sahihBukhari/071.sbt.html).

The Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) also said :

**Sunan Abu Dawud Book 22, Number 3846**:

> Narrated Usamah ibn Sharik:
>
> I came to the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) and his Companions were sitting as if they had birds on their heads. I saluted and sat down.
>   The desert Arabs then came from here and there. They asked: Apostle of
>   Allah, should we make use of medical treatment? He replied: Make use
>   of medical treatment, for Allah has not made a disease without
>   appointing a remedy for it, with the exception of one disease, namely
>   old age.

**Sunan Abu Dawud, Book 22, Number 3855:**

> Narrated Jabir ibn Abdullah:
>
> The Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) sent a physician to Ubayy (ibn
>   Ka'b), and he cut his vein.

Muslim scholars have agreed that adopting the proper and Islamically permissible means to reach a specific end and does not contradict Tawakkul (putting one’s trust in Allah).

Since, the question is about the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) himself, it is also known that he used to get cupped (Hijamah) when he had any ailment which is a prophetic solution as well.

**Sahih Bukhari, Volume 7, Book 71, Number 595:**

> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas:
>
> The Prophet was cupped and he paid the wages to the one who had
>   cupped him and then took Su'ut (Medicine sniffed by nose).

**Sahih Bukhari, Volume 7, Book 71, Number 602:**

> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas:
>
> The Prophet was cupped on his head for an ailment he was suffering
>   from while he was in a state of Ihram. at a water place called Lahl
>   Jamal. Ibn 'Abbas further said: Allah s Apostle was cupped on his head
>   for unilateral headache while he was in a state of Ihram .

Answer (score 3):

The assumption that the Prophet(pbuh) never fell sick is incorrect.
See Sahih Bukhari Book #11, Hadith #646

> **Narrated Abu Musa:**
>
> "The Prophet became sick and when his disease became aggravated..."

BUT I would agree with your teacher that it is recommended to eat less to be healthy.

#### Why the Prophet(pbuh) never went to the doctor?

There are certain rules that apply only to the Prophet(pbuh). For example, the Prophet's wives cannot re-marry etc.

In this case it is seeking cure from someone else. If the Prophet(pbuh) fell sick and went to the doctor, the unbelievers would say "He goes to the doctor but cannot ask Allah for a cure whose prophet he claims to be".

If you refer to the quran...

> **"And when I am ill, it is He Who cures me;" [Quran 26:80]**

The above verse applies to us and to the Prophet(pbuh), but since the Prophet(pbuh) had a direct connection with Allah he got the cure directly.

Hence you will see many books of topics like "Cures of the Prophet(pbuh)", "Medicine of the Prophet(pbuh)" etc.

**In short, the Prophet(pbuh) was doctor himself and had learnt his cures from the best university in the world (Allah)**

Answer (score 0):

Use of Hijjamah was one of the medical practices. use of Talbeena: a mixture of Barley, Milk and Paste of dates or Honey as conveyed by Arch angel Jibrael to the Holy Prophet SAW when the latter sought remedy for generalised weakness, malaise etc
In the compilation of Tib-e-Nabvi we have references to series of remedies for various ailments prescribed by the Holy Prophet SAW . 
But there is no ref about his going to a doctor or Hakeem. Rather Allah SWT transferred knowledge about medicinal value and use of various fruits, herbs, use of Hijamah(cupping therapy), use of leaches etc to him.

Answer (score 0):

Al Harith ibn Kalada was the doctor of the Prophet SAWS.

Comment: Please add sources and evdinces to support your claims and read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

To supplement Abdullah's [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2053/20218), there is a narration in which Urwa asked Ayesha about the source of her knowledge of medicine on which she replied:

<sub>**Note:** The English translations below are my own, so treat with caution as may contain paraphrasing etc.</sub>

> إن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم كان يسقم عند آخر عمره، أو في آخر عمره، فكانت تقدم عليه وفود العرب من كل وجه، فتنعت له الأنعات، وكنت أعالجها له، فمن ثم
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ got ill in the latter part of his life and the delegations of the Arabs came to him from every place, they would prescribe medicines and I would treat with them
>
> <sup>— [Musnad Ahmad](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/20583)</sup>

> إن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم كان رجلا مسقاما وكان أطباء العرب يأتونه فأتعلم منهم
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ got ill and the healers of the Arabs came to him and I learnt from listening to them.
>
> <sup>—  [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/8264)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Prophet Muhammad had no use to goto any doctor because was a very good doctor himself, thats why there was no need to goto any doctor. He used to cure his diseases on his own, without anyone's help.

Answer (score -2):

Prophets/Imams are the greatest humans in terms of being the most humble before Allah. Yet they are weak beings like every other human. They get sick, they get beaten, they get betrayed, they get tired, they get informed (through divine means. nonetheless without divine aid they are humans) etc.

Yet unlike every other human they never get outsmarted nor ever speak beyond their reach.

(Due to the higher position of Prophets and Imams among Shias it's generally more common among them to think of Prophets/Imams as beings unlike other humans which they are. But not every sense. They have a tremendous amount of similarities with us)